# wordpress get menu item and post_name

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Is there an easy way to get the menu item title and post_name in a simple loop. I tried everything, but nothing worked.

E.g. I tried it with following code:

```
$args = array(
                        'order'                  => 'ASC',
                        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
                        'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
                        'post_status'            => 'publish',
                        'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
                        'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
                        'nopaging'               => true,
                        'update_post_term_cache' => false );

                    $menu = wp_get_nav_menu_items('main-menu', $args);
                    foreach($menu as $page){
                      echo $page->title." | ";
                      echo $page->post_name."<br/>";
                    }
```

The title works but the post_name always returns the ID of the item. Any idea?

Best regards,
Yab86